# CSS table inside absolute div

Tags: css, css-position

Please see in [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BeeUY/2/):

html:

```
    <div class="r">
    <div class="e_1">xxx</div>
    <div class="e_2">

        <div class="e_c" >

            <table class="e_c">
                <tr>
                    <td>dsdssdsds</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ssss</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.r {
    position: relative;
}

.e_1 {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.e_2 {
     position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.e_c {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

As you can see in the code (it's just a demo of my real case), I put a table inside the `div` `.e_2`. But when this is rendered by the browser, the `table` does not show up inside the `.e2` element; I want the `.e_2` `div` to wrap the `table`. And the expected result is have red border around the table.

How I can do that if not change the HTML structure ?

Comment: e_2 has no dimensions.

Comment: [Don't use `position: absolute;`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BeeUY/3/). Also, when the error message tells you to post code, and not *just a link to JS Fiddle*, post your code *here*; don't pretend that your link to the demo is code (it's not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want **just** the table to have a red border use the border property:

```
border:1px solid red;
```

So in your case would be:

```
.e_c {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

However if you really want the div to wrap around your table change the property of position from e_c and e_2 to relative:

```
.e_2 {
     position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.e_c {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 0; 
}
```

This would however make the div extend to the whole width unless you add the **display** property to your .e_2 class:

```
.e_2 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I really want the div to wrap around the table. Could you explain for me more how you know use "relative" in this case? I'm not clear this point :)

Comment: This positioning is really a confusing deal and I would try to avoid using it unless extremely necessary. Absolute positions itself accordingly to its parent element (if it has absolute or relative position too) which is not ideal for every element on the page. The relative means relative to itself, that is you set a position relative to where it would be! Read more about here: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ and http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: However as I said... try to avoid it... your example doesn't even need the positioning (if you try to set all positions by hand you are going to get crazy) just imagine the divs as little boxes that can be side by side or stacked up. Here is your example with only the useful parts: http://jsfiddle.net/BeeUY/6/

Answer (score 0):

See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/designingsean/BeeUY/5/

The biggest issue is that the table does not need to be position:absolute, since its parent already is. That corrects the table placement, but then the border is not right. The best way to fix this is to put the border on the table itself, rather than the containing div.

The affected portions of the CSS:

```
.e_2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0px;  
}

.e_c {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.e_c table.e_c {
    border:1px solid red
}
```